# How to move a .tar.gz file from one directory to another directory

Tags: centos

i have a file latest.tar.gz i have to move this file to another folder.

example: file is in this path root/home/phani

```
     i have to move this file to root/san/newwebsite/
```

am new to centOS pls help me grt out of from this.

Comment: mv current_file new/path

Answer (score 6):

In a shell window, type:

```
 mv /root/home/phani/latest.tar.gz /root/san/newwebsite/
```

Comment: it showing mv: cannot move '/root/home/phani/latest.tar.gz' to'/root/san/newwebsite/':permission denied

Comment: Then this is not a programming question anymore. As which user did you run that command? Make sure you have the appropriate permissions. Or run that command as `root` user.